# Xcode doesn't see the file

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode5

I have this file structure:

[image]

But Xcode doesn't see file for :`#import "VKSdk.h"` , because it's in another project, what do I need to do:

Comment: YOu need to properly import your another project to current one..

Comment: Click on the file, open the right-hand file attributes window, and click the checkmark to add it to your project.

Comment: put those files into your project folder then right click on your project and select add files to your project and dont forgot to check Copy item into destination group's folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VK guid said to add only sdk.xcodeproj file, so it didn't see all the files in this added project, but when I tried to cope these files into the project, it failed to launch.

I added $(PROJECT_DIR)/DatingService/3d\ Party/VKAPI/sdk into Header Search Paths of Build Settings and now it works.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps consider looking into how to work with workspaces in Xcode. It offers great features when working with multiple interconnected projects.

Check this out
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Workspace.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean your project. I hope it helps

[image]

Answer (score 0):

File is not present make sure you are writing right class name

Make sure file is present over there.

If you are adding file from somewhere it is recommended to tick the check box copy item into destination folder.

Answer (score 0):

**Fix**: you need to update User Header Search Paths in Build Settings like this **../**** 
Look at the image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/beytwz8ev262l53/header_vksdk_fix.png